# How to set and update properties on existing nodes via CSV file using SPARQL on GraphDB

Tags: csv, sparql, openrefine, graphdb, ontorefine

I would like to set a new property to existing nodes whose type is `:Disease`. The CSV file has two columns. The first has the header `Disease_Name` and the second one has the header `Disease_Class`. I want to match the nodes (`subject ?disease`) for which the property `:name` has the same value as the value of the cells in the `Disease_Name` column, and create a new property (`:class`) with the same value as the one of the cell (in the same row) in the `Disease_Class` column.

```sparql
INSERT {
    ?disease a :Disease ;
        stbio:class ?Disease_Class.
        
} WHERE {
    SERVICE <ontorefine:2512803899077> {
        ?row a :Row ;
            :Disease_Name ?Disease_Name ;
            :Disease_Class ?Disease_Class.
        ?disease stbio:name ?Disease_Name.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with GraphDB, but perhaps you should put the last line outside of the SERVICE query.

INSERT {
    ?disease a :Disease ;
        stbio:class ?Disease_Class.
        
} WHERE {

        ?disease stbio:name ?Disease_Name.
    SERVICE <ontorefine:2512803899077> {
        ?row a :Row ;
            :Disease_Name ?Disease_Name ;
            :Disease_Class ?Disease_Class.
    
    
    }
}

Comment: may I ask what does not work with the query?

Comment: i needed to put the last line out of the SERVICE query as @ValerioCocchi said. Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

If stbio:class is a class, maybe you also need to do some manipulation of `?Disease_Class` which would be a string?

Answered (so it doesn't appear in `[graphdb] answers:0` again).